# Unable to install package web.codegeneration.design version 6.0.7

Tags: c#, nuget

I try to download web.codegeneration.design version 6.0.7 in visual studio 2022  but i had error
And that is the error message:

> The feed 'nuget.org (https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json) lists package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.6.0.7' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again.
> Unable to find package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.6.0.7'.

How i can solve it      ?!!

Comment: If you run the command in Package Manager - `Install-Package` - you might get an error message there which could help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have wrong package name, you are missing the "Design"-part:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design -Version 6.0.7
```

See here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design/#versions-body-tab

Comment: I tried it and no result

Comment: What do you mean no results?

Comment: I meant i still have errors

Comment: Your original error was 'Unable to find package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.6.0.7' which cannot happen with this command. So what is the error you are getting when running this command?

Comment: I got this error from manager console